# Ravendb single or multiple indexes needed?

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have a simple document structure such as:

```
public class CulturedData
{
    public string Culture { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public List<CulturedData> Titles { get; set; }
    public List<CulturedData> Descriptions { get; set; }
}

Culture = "EN" or "DE" or "FR" etc.
```

I am wondering the best way to keyword search for products using their respective Text properties. The Text content for Descriptions could be quite large, maybe 20-30K. What is the best way to index this sort of data, and would I need a separate index for each culture?

It would also be nice to use the *More Like This* feature, so does this mean I am forced down a particular indexing path?

Any further questions/explanation please ask.

Regards
Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single index, like this:

```
from p in products
select new
{
   _ = p.Titles.Select(x=>CreateField("Titles_" + x.Culture, x.Text)),
   _+ = p.Descriptions.Select(x=>CreateField("Descriptions_" + x.Culture, x.Text)),
}
```

And that should give you what you want.